# Adding a list of objects to my Firestore collection

Tags: android, for-loop, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I have a list of a model of mine called GroupMemberEntity.

I want to set that list into my collection, each one getting its own unique ID using UUID.

My current implementation is the following -

```kotlin
suspend fun addGroupMembers(
        groupId: String,
        users: List<GroupMemberEntity>
    ) = suspendCoroutine<ResponseHandler.Resource<Any>> { continuation ->
        var insertCounter = 1
        users.forEach { entity ->
            FIRESTORE_DATABASE.collection(ACTIVITIES_COLLECTION)
                .document(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .set(entity)
                .addOnSuccessListener {
                    insertCounter++
                    if (insertCounter != users.size) return@addOnSuccessListener
                    continuation.resume(responseHandler.handleSuccess())

                }
                .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
                    continuation.resume(responseHandler.handleException(exception))
                }
        }
    }
```

I have a feeling this can be improved by not using the `forEach` loop, but I'm not sure how. doing a network call in a loop seems like a bad idea in general.

Any advice would be helpful.

Comment: May I ask why you are using the listener approach and not the dependency provide my `kotlin-coroutines`? And may I ask why every entity of your list needs its own document?

Comment: @Andrew about the listener approach - if you have anything better I would be glad to hear. About the entities having their own document - this how I decided to structure my remote DB. Again, if you have a better suggestion I would be glad to hear.

Answer (score 1):

If you want each entity to have its own document, than you need to use the `for-each` approach:

```
suspend fun addGroupMember(groupId: String, user: List<GroupMemberEntity>) {
   users.forEach {
       FIRESTORE_DATABASE.collection(ACTIVITIES_COLLECTION)
                .document(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .set(entity)
                .await()
   }
}
```

Another, maybe easier approach would be to just post the entire list in one document. You can later retrieve or (I think) query within this document for a specific field. For this, I would add a `uuid` to your `GroupMemberEntity`. But I am not 100% sure if this works.